# Change CSS for all same-class-elements when hovering over a single same-class-element

Tags: jquery, css

I'm looking to change the background-color for ALL cells with class="bg" when hovering ANY cell with class="bg".

Hours of stuff like `$('.bg').hover().css("background-color","blue");` and trying out 
with `.each()`,  `.mouseover()`, and even `.siblings()` (although i think that's entirely off the mark) but no result.

```
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .bg { background-color:red; }
                    .bg:hover { background-color:blue; }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <table width="100" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         <tr>
              <td class="bg">a</td>
              <td class="bg">a</td>
              <td class="bg">a</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <table width="100" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         <tr>
              <td class="bg">a</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
              <td class="bg">a</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
              <td class="bg">a</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
         </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

EDIT: After kumiau's working solution I realized that what I'm looking for is far more complex. [This is the page I'm working on](http://goo.gl/Hd3c3). Hovering over ANY *Hole 1* cell in either of the dark grey sections and ALL *Hole 1* cell background-colors change.

Now, that page only shows 1 game type (Fourball Best Ball) with 1 round (Dubin/Kosakewitsch
VS Dybkjær/Larsen), but there will be 3 types  (Fourball Best ball, Foursomes, Singles), with 6 rounds each, with 18 holes each. That's 324 holes! [See last year's tournament here](http://goo.gl/wtYcY).

So, ahem, that changes things quite a bit. I'm thinking that I could class every hole cell similarly (simply, class="hole") and store the *HoleID* in a data attribute (something like data-hole-id="fbb_1_4" for Fourball Best Ball, Round 1, Hole 4), in order to make a more general jQ function??

EDIT 2: Got the last bit answered here [jQuery selector madness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657749/jquery-selector-madness)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.bg').hover(
  function(){
    $('.bg').css({"background-color":"blue"});
  },function(){
    $('.bg').css({"background-color":"white"});
});
```

updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kumiau/Nkdny/3/

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick!
Just for shits&giggles: I have the bgcolor set in a separate stylesheet. Using this jQ overrides the bgcolor on the first hover, and the stylesheet colour is never seen again. Any workaround?? (simply removing the second hover function leaves the cells blue...)

Comment: You're right. it's better to return to the css defined color. I updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kumiau/Nkdny/4/

Comment: Brilliant! After plugging this in and seeing it working I realized what I'm looking for is far more complex. Question edited (quite a bit)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.bg').data('bg', $('.bg').css('background-color')).on({
    mouseenter: function() {
       $('.bg').css('background-color', 'cyan');
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
       $('.bg').css('background-color', $(this).data('bg'));
    }
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/TSZkL/)