# jQuery selector madness

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

The following code performs `.css({"background":"black"});` on all elements with `class="hole"`, however I'm trying to get it to do it on elements with `class="hole"` AND `data-hole-key="[hole_key_variable]"`.

What's missing?

jQuery:

```
// on elements with class "hole" hovered
$('.hole').hover(
    function(){ 
        // get the data value of the currently hovered element
        var holeKey = $($(this).data('holeKey'));
        // on all elements with that class "hole" and specified data value, change bgcolor
        $('.hole').data(holeKey).css({"background":"black"});
    },
    function(){
        var holeKey = $($(this).data('holeKey'));
        $('.hole').data(holeKey).removeAttr('style');
    }
);
```

HTML:

```
<td class="hole" data-hole-key="1">text</td>
<td class="hole" data-hole-key="2">text</td>
<td class="hole" data-hole-key="3">text</td>
```

BTW, why does this (faulty) code not work at all without double wrapping this line:

```
var holeKey = $($(this).data('holeKey'));
```

Comment: Have you tried combining your selectors, e.g. `$('.hole[data-hole-key]');` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working jsfiddle of what I believe you're looking for:
http://jsfiddle.net/XKs4a/

```
// on elements with class "hole" hovered
$('.hole').hover(
    function(){
        // get the data value of the currently hovered element
        var holeKey = $(this).data('holeKey');
        // on all elements with that class "hole" and specified data value, change bgcolor
        $('.hole[data-hole-key=' + holeKey + ']').css({"background":"black"});
    },
    function(){
        var holeKey = $(this).data('holeKey');
        $('.hole[data-hole-key=' + holeKey + ']').removeAttr('style');
    }
);
```

And for this:

```
var holeKey = $($(this).data('holeKey'));
```

That would return the key wrapped in jquery, so for the first element you would get $(1)

Comment: Thanks, that works! I wasn't aware of the square bracket selection option. Looking into it, lots to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
Rethinking what I think you are trying to do- this first snipped will change the hovered element CSS only

```
$('.hole').hover(
    function(){ 

    $(this).css({"background":"black"});
    },
    function(){

      $(this).removeAttr('style');
    }
);
```

**WHere your code is causing issues**

This part here is not going to return a value because you are wrapping it in jQuery, and the value being wrapped is not a selector

```
    // get the data value of the currently hovered element
    var holeKey = $($(this).data('holeKey'));
```

To get the value from element data

```
    // get the data value of the currently hovered element
    var holeKey = $(this).data('holeKey');
```

To isolate a $('.hole') based on its data value you could do something like this:

```
 var testVal=1;

  $('.hole[data-hole-key="'+ testVal+'"]').hover(.....
```

Or another method using filter()

```
    var testVal=1;

    $('.hole').filter(function(){
            return $(this).data('data-hole-key')==testVal;                 
    }).hover(....
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The first piece of code wasn't exactly what I was looking for but I learnt a few tricks from the following parts :)

Comment: description was hard to follow based on non working code as reference.. answer chosen is actually a long way around using my edited solution of using "this" and adds extra DOM search to it